# Table controls not showing on TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have the following code to use TinyMCE which all works except for the tablecontrols part.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".wysiwyg",
    plugins: "textcolor,table",
    menubar : false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar1: "bold italic underline | numlist bullist outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link",
    toolbar2: "hr | fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | tablecontrols",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            $(".wysiwyg").html(editor.getContent());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace the comma in the plugins value with a space like

plugins: "textcolor table",

I'm using the following

....
plugins: "link image code paste table",
menubar: false,
toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic | link image table | code",
....